# Use ObjectOutputStream and FileOutputStream with FileWriter

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

Is there any way to use `ObjectOutputStream` like this:

```
<tag>output of the ObjectOutputStream</tag>
```

If I try:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fos);
```

And for example:

```
fw.write("<tag>");
oos.write(cool_object);
fw.wrote("</tag>");
```

I don't get that result. It seems the `ObjectOutputStream` overwrites the file completly each and every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following binary output.

```
oos.writeObject("<tag>");
oos.writeObject(cool_object);
oos.writeObject("</tag>");
```

OR text output

```
fw.write("<tag>"+cool_object+"</tag>");
```

EDIT: You may need to encode the output of cool_object.toString() if it contains and HTML special characters.

Comment: There may be several problems, if your `cool_object` contains String like '<tag>' or other XML Entities. It may be better if you use an XML-Framework or convert your binary into an Base64-String, as @Bozho mentioned.

Comment: should we assume you meant `oos.writeObject(..)` ? This will output 3 objects - 2 strings and 1 custom. But the string object representation after serialization is unlikely to be `<tag>`

Comment: @Bozho, you are correct. The binary file will contain `<tag>` and `</tag>` as well as alot of binary which you won't be able to read as text.

Comment: XML is not a solution. I don't like replacing my problems ;) Java seems to disklike most attempts to persist objects into file or to store/read low-level byte-representations. Still I'm nore sure how I can read cool_object again, but I'll find a way.

Comment: @wishi, There are lots of different ways to store an object in a file.  You need to be more specific about your requirements. There are at least two standard ways built into Java and dozens of libraries to do it different ways.

Answer (score 4):

No - a `FileWriter` is for writing *text*, but the output of `ObjectOutputStream` is inherently *binary* data. If you want to serialize objects to XML, use a serializer which *knows* about XML, e.g. [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The `ObjectOutputStream` makes a binary representation. So you must first turn that into a string representation - either hex or Base64

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
String str = Base64.encodeBase64(baos.toByteArray());
```

then write this `str` between the tags.

If you want an xml representation, rather than a binary representation, then you can use the [`XMLEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) which is the xml version of `ObjectOutputStream`